# Send POST request when back button is pressed or before app is killed

Tags: android, post, android-volley, activity-lifecycle

```
First part
```

I have to send a post request to the server only when the the activity is done with. It may be because back button was pressed or app is closed. Does the method *isFinishing* called when back button is pressed?

```
Second part
```

What should i do for situation where app has suddenly crashed and it is unable to send the data?

By the way i am using volley for all the network operations.

Answer (score 0):

1. `isFinishing` isn't called, it's a check you can make to see what caused the `Activity` to finish. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29). What you mean is `onDestroy`. You can put your POST request there, but arguably, that is not the best situation and timing to perform HTTP calls.
2. If an app crashes it crashes. You can't stop the crash to perform other actions, because it's a crash.

You should consider using the disk as cache for the data you want to send, and in an event of a crash, when the app is loaded next time, read the data from the disk and send it.